# Best way to create a skills matrix in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: custom-list

I'm new to these forums. I am a Front End user of sharepoint (no SharePoint designer access) and would like to understand the best ways to go about utilising sharepoint lists. 
At the moment I'm doing a piece of work for a Contact Centre.
There are 200 colleagues - Each colleague can have upto 3 possible skill sets 
Service
Support
Business

Each skillset has about 100 - 200 enquiry types in them. The Business would like to measure the COMPETENCY of each colleague (by Team)  in each skill set (as a %)
We currently use excel spreadsheets (attached) to do this. But this is becoming really cumbersome.  When a colleague moves teams, you have to create a new sheet, when they get a new skills (like a service colleague becomes support) you have to create a new sheet. When the enquiry types change, you have to change the sheet for every colleague, which is just a nightmare.

Can sharepoint facilitate this functionality. I'm very proficient with lists, however the data entry side would be huge.. considering I'd have to make a list database with almost 300 entries in it

Also , we're upgrading to SharePoint 2013 in the near future, would that version of SharePoint have enhanced functionality that would assist me in this endeavour?

ANy help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Just found out I cannot attach, so if you think you can help, please send me your email and I will email this to you :)

Comment: Email me the sheet.. You can use basic Lookup columns to get related lists, but for more flexibility you will need to do development.. Let me see what you can achieve OOB !